# Incorrect result after removing first node from Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote this code to delete the first node in a singly linked list.

```
CreateLinkedList(node **headPtr)
{
    int i;
    node *pMyNode;
    pMyNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //create space for first node []
    *headPtr=pMyNode;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pMyNode->element = i; //enter value [0]
        printf("Value is %d addr is %p\n",pMyNode->element,pMyNode);
        pMyNode->nextPtr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //[0]->[]->NULL
        pMyNode = pMyNode->nextPtr;
    }
    pMyNode->nextPtr=NULL;
}

void PrintLinkedList(node **headPtr)
{
    node *pMyNode;
    int i;
    pMyNode=*headPtr;
    while(pMyNode)
    {
        printf("Value is %d addr is %p\n",pMyNode->element,pMyNode);
        pMyNode = pMyNode->nextPtr;
    }
}

void DeleteANode(node **headPtr)
{
    node *pMyNode; //head->[]->[]->[]->NULL
    pMyNode=*headPtr;
    *headPtr=*headPtr->nextPtr;
    free(pMyNode);

}
int main()
{   
    node *pNode;
    CreateLinkedList(&pNode);
    DeleteANode(&pNode);
    PrintLinkedList(&pNode);
}
```

Output I am getting is :

Before deleting

```
value is 0 addr is 8e75008 
value is 1 addr is 8e75018
value is 2 addr is 8e75028
value is 3 addr is 8e75038
value is 4 addr is 8e75048
value is 5 addr is 8e75058
value is 6 addr is 8e75068
value is 7 addr is 8e75078
value is 8 addr is 8e75088
value is 9 addr is 8e75098
```

After Deleting

```
value is 0 addr is 8e75008 // This node should not be printed
value is 0 addr is 8e75018 
value is 2 addr is 8e75028
value is 3 addr is 8e75038
value is 4 addr is 8e75048
value is 5 addr is 8e75058
value is 6 addr is 8e75068
value is 7 addr is 8e75078
value is 8 addr is 8e75088
value is 9 addr is 8e75098
```

Comment: please show more complete code.  You dont show where a node is getting created/initialized, or added to the list and the code calling all this.

Comment: Is DeletaANode meant to remove the node at the head of the list? If so, why would 8e75018 be the node that should not be printed in your example; shouldn't 8375008 be the node that should not be printed?

Comment: Correct. I just edited my post.

Comment: You should change the loop in PrintLinkedList to use `while(pMyNode != NULL)`. Currently it is always looping 10 times, but there may no longer be 10 nodes in the list (as would be after deleting one).

Comment: I tried that too. But still the same result.

Comment: Also, the last node to be malloc'd and added to the list will not be getting it's element value set based on how you have the initialization setup. You should start with a run through this logic using a debugger to examine your variables throughout the steps of the creation/deletion/printing processes.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I'm amazed it accepts this code without errors or big fat warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is the following statement:

```
*headPtr=*headPtr->nextPtr;
```

`->` has a higher precedence than `*` so it is evaluated first.  To dereference the pointer first, you need parentheses:

```
*headPtr=(*headPtr)->nextPtr;
```

Another problem is the following block:

```
pMyNode=*headPtr;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("Value is %d addr is %p\n",pMyNode->element,pMyNode);
    pMyNode = pMyNode->nextPtr;
}
```

You should not hard-code how many links there are.  Instead use a `while` loop and check for `NULL`:

```
pMyNode=*headPtr;
while(pMyNode)
{
    printf("Value is %d addr is %p\n",pMyNode->element,pMyNode);
    pMyNode = pMyNode->nextPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line of DeleteANode: `*headPtr=*headPtr->nextPtr;`

I believe it should be `*headPtr=(*headPtr)->nextPtr;`

I'm not sure why your version does not throw an error/warning on the line as you have it. The assignment of *headPtr should be expecting another pointer to node and you are dereferencing headPtr->nextPtr thereby attempting to assign a node structure to *headPtr?!